# Python Django Global Variables

Tags: python, django, memory, variables, global

I'm looking for simple but recommended way in Django to store a variable in memory only.  When Apache restarts or the Django development server restarts, the variable is reset back to 0.  More specifically, I want to count how many times a particular action takes place on each model instance (database record), but for performance reasons, I don't want to store these counts in the database.  I don't care if the counts disappear after a server restart.  But as long as the server is up, I want these counts to be consistent between the Django shell and the web interface, and I want to be able to return how many times the action has taken place on each model instance.

I don't want the variables to be associated with a user or session because I might want to return these counts without being logged in (and I want the counts to be consistent no matter what user is logged in).  Am I describing a global variable?  If so, how do I use one in Django?   I've noticed the files like the urls.py, settings.py and models.py seems to be parsed only once per server startup (by contrast to the views.py which seems to be parsed eache time a request is made).  Does this mean I should declare my variables in one of those files?  Or should I store it in a model attribute somehow (as long as it sticks around for as long as the server is running)?  This is probably an easy question, but I'm just not sure how it's done in Django.

Any comments or advice is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Joe

Comment: The caching docs are a bit 'caching-a-page' centric. Jump to 'low-level' for details on using it for server variables: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api

Comment: This might help you:
[https://github.com/andres-torres-marroquin/django-system-globals](https://github.com/andres-torres-marroquin/django-system-globals)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You **mustn't** declare global variables. Settings (constants) are OK if done right. But variables violate with *shared-nothing* architecture and might cause a lot of trouble. (best case they'll be inconsistent)

I would simply store those statistics in the cache. (Well, actually I would store them in the database but you made clear you *believe* it will have a negative impact on performance, so...)

The new `incr()` and `decr()` methods are especially suitable for counting. See  [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api) for more info.

Comment: I like this approach, and am implementing it.  Currently I am using localmem for the cache backend on the Django development server and have noticed that the counts don't persist after browsing through several web pages in my site. (In which time I did NOT restart the django development server)  I realize that there could be multiple reasons for this.  (Eventually I'll use memcached).  Just wondering if the localmem cache / django development server doesn't hold onto cached values long or if I have a config setting wrong somehow.

Comment: @Joe: I always use db cache in the absence of a proper cache backend such as memcached. Just to be sure. This goes together with "not worrying at all about performance problems until they are apparent" and "measure before optimize".

Comment: @muhuk I've a question regarding global variables in Django views. Can please provide your views ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490843/django-app-level-variables

Comment: @PankajSinghal I've read your question. Middleware seems like a good way to go. But I'm probably not the best person to answer, it's been a long time I've worked with Django.

Comment: What about global object such as GeoIP database readers? Opening it in every request hurts a lot :)

Comment: @arts777 that is a good use case IMO. Unfortunately variables are, well, mutable in Python. I would suggest providing such immutable values with a function and caching its result. That way you would prevent the database accidentally being overwritten. Of course you would probably want to make sure the value is somehow immutable as well.

Comment: @muhuk can you please take a look at this question, related to global GeoIP bases? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358525/maxmind-geoip2-single-instance-in-django

Comment: I did. It's been a while since I've written Python code professionally. Better to get feedback from more up-to-date people.

Answer (score 76):

Why one **mustn't** declare global variables? O_o. It just looks like a propaganda. If the author knows what he wants and what side-effects will be, why not. Maybe it's just a quick experiment.

You could declare your counter as a model *class*-member. Then to deal with race condition you have to add a method that will wait if some other client, from another thread works with counter. Something like this:

```
import threading

class MyModel(ModelBase):
    _counter = 0
    _counter_lock = threading.Lock()

    @classmethod
    def increment_counter(cls):
        with cls._counter_lock:
            cls._counter += 1

    def some_action(self):
        # core code
        self.increment_counter()


# somewhere else
print MyModel._counter
```

Remember however: you have to have your application in one *process*. So if you've deployed the application under Apache, be sure it is configured to spawn many threads, but not many processes. If you're experimenting with `./manage.py run` no actions are required.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I need to generate a serial id that would be incremented for each request for testing purpose. In actual system, the id is coming from external API.

Comment: This might be a viable approach for toy projects. But once you start using this class you've guaranteed that your application is not scalable. There is a reason why we have the cache sub-system.

Comment: i used this approach to instantiate once a client to a machine service, instantiate it every time slow down my webserver...

Comment: Does EVERY application need to be scalable?

Comment: Considering the GIL, is the threading part necessary? Are there django configurations where actual multi-threading is happening within a process and race conditions are a concern?

Comment: @nailxx I've a question regarding global variables in Django views. Can please provide your views ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490843/django-app-level-variables

Answer (score 3):

I would create a "config.py" file on the root directory. and put all global variables inside:

```
x = 10
my_string = ''
```

at "view.py":

```
from your_project import config

def MyClass(reuqest):
    y = config.x + 20
    my_title = config.my_string
...
```

The benefit of creating this file is the variables can cross multiple .py files and it is easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the hassle with Django database, e.g. migrations or performance issues, you might consider in-memory database [redis](https://redis.io/). Redis guarantees consistency even if there are multiple Django processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables from settings.py

see below example. It's an app that counts requests

## settings.py

```
REQ_COUNTER = 0
```

## View.py

```py
from {**your project folder name **}.settings import REQ_COUNTER 

def CountReq(request):
 global = REQ_COUNTER
 REQ_COUNTER = REQ_COUNTER + 1
 return HttpResponse(REQ_COUNTER)
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[multiprocessing.Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Manager) may be used to share variables between all Django sub-processes started by a main process:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

total_count = Manager().Value('i', 0)

@api_view(['GET'])
def hello_count(request):
    total_count.value = total_count.value + 1
    return Response(data={'count': total_count.value})
```

`total_count` will be increased for all running processes (checked with multiple workers running by `gunicorn` app server).

However, if you will run `python manage.py shell` the `total_count` will be `0` for this process, because that is a separated master process with own memory space. If you want to get the same shared value for all processes inside server (or even multiple servers) you have to use in-memory DB (`redis`, etc), what is better and more stable practice for production environments.