# django vars in ram

Tags: python, django, global-variables

I am implementing a really lightweight Web Project, which has just one page, showing data in a diagram. I use Django as a Webserver and d3.js as plotting routine for this diagram. As you can imagine, there are just a few simple time series which have to be responded by Django server, so I was wondering if I simply could hold this variable in ram. My first test was positive, I had something like this in my views.py:

```
X = np.array([123,23,1,32,123,1])

@csrf_exempt
def getGraph(request):
    global X
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(X))
```

Notice, `X` is updated by another function every now and then, but all user access is read-only. Do I have to deal with

1. security issues by defining a global variable?
2. inconsistencies in general?

I found [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680902/python-django-global-variables) discussing global variables in Django, but in that case, the difficulty is of handling multiple write-access.

To answer potential questions on why I don't want store data in database: All data I got in my `X` is already stored in a huge remote database and this web app just needs to display data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing it in a variable does indeed have threading implications (and also scalibility - what if you have two Django servers running the same app?). The advice from the Django community is *don't*!.

This sounds like a good fit for the Django cache system though. Just cache your `getGraph` view with `@cache_page` and the job is done. No need to use memcache, the built-in in-memory memory-cache cache-backend<sup>*</sup> will work fine. Put a very high number as the time-out on the cache (years).

This way you are storing the HTTP response (JSON) not the value of X. But from your code sample, that is not a problem. If you need to re-calculate X you need to re-calculate the JSON, and if you need to re-calculate the JSON you will need to re-calculate X.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs/

---

<sup>1</sup> or just 'built-in memory backend', I couldn't resist

Comment: As a member of the Django community, I wouldn't necessarily say "don't" - I've done a few things very similar myself. But +1 for the cache backend, it's a much better way to solve this problem.

Comment: @Joe I tried this, and it works fine with normal http requests, but when I call it via `AJAX` it is not cached. I guess, Django considers every single `AJAX`-request to be different from the one before and computes `X` again. How to deal with that? But thanks, again for recommending Django cache system - it seems to be quite more elegant than global vars

Comment: don't mind! I solved it by using the `The low-level cache API`. It's just perfect. Thanks a lot