# How to preload django's view at application start?

Tags: django, global-variables

I wrote some global variable which takes some time to initial in views.py. Instead of responding after requesting, I would like to make those variable initialed while the server starting. Is there any way to do it? I have try google about it but in vain. I think I couldn't be the first one have this kinda of needs. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a pretty good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680902/python-django-global-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are talking about settigs, that means, variables that are fixed at start time.

You can set this kind of vars in `settigs.py`  and access them importing settings:

**settings.py**

```
MYSETTING = some expression
```

**views.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
...
mycalc = ... MYSETTINGS ...
```