# Global Variable Django

Tags: python, django

I have two template in django:

first, i give name index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="formulir">
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="label">Username</div><div class="input"><input type="text" name="username"/></div>
            <div class="label">Email</div><div class="input"><input type="text" name="email"/></div>
            <input type="submit" name="tambah" value="Add"/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="data">
        {% block data %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Second, i give name data.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block data %}
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        {% for i in data %}
            <tr>{{ i.username }}</tr>
            <tr>{{ i.email }}</tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to do when form in index.html submitted, the data show in data.html and when I submitted for the second time the data.html show 2 data, so the first data still exist. I don't want to save the data to database.

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

global data
data = []
def home(request):
    if request.POST:
        data = data.append(request.POST)
        return render_to_response('data.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response('index.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

anybody can help me?

Comment: If it's not saved to a database, how would the data survive across requests?

Comment: May be in session or otherways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using global variables is bad practice overall but you may use it if your application run with one system process: [Python Django Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680902/python-django-global-variables). You can save data in session or you need to put all posted data **to form and repost it in hidden inputs** for example if you need to get it without saving anywhere:

```
...
<div id="formulir">
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="label">Username</div><div class="input"><input type="text" name="username"/></div>
        <div class="label">Email</div><div class="input"><input type="text" name="email"/></div>
        <input type="submit" name="tambah" value="Add"/>

        {% for i in data %}
            <input type="hidden" name="username" value="{{ i.username }}"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ i.email }}"/>
        {% endfor %}

    </form>
</div>
....
```

To create `data` variable and access to it in templates with code like that `{{ i.username }}` you need some logic in view:

```
def home(request):
    data = []
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.getlist('username')
        email = request.POST.getlist('email')
        data = [{'username': u, 'email': e} for u, e in zip(username, email)]
        return render_to_response('data.html', locals(),
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response('index.html', locals(),
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```