# Very slow to write to Django cache

Tags: django, caching, django-cache

I used to cache a database query in a global variable to speed up my application. Since this is strongly unadvised (and it did generate problems), I want to use any kind of Django cache instead. I tried LocMemCache and DatabaseCache, but both take... about **15 seconds** to set my variable (twice longer than it take to generate the data, which is 7MB in size).

Is that expected ? Am I doing something wrong ?

(Memcached is limited to 1MB, and I cannot split my data, which consists in arbitrarily big binary masks).

*Edit: FileBasedCache takes 30s to set as well.*

Settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {...},
    'stats': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache', 
        # or 'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'stats',
    },
}
```

Service.py:

```
from django.core.cache import caches

def stats_service():
    stats_cache = caches['stats']
    if stats_cache.get('key') is None:
        stats_cache.set('key', data)  # 15s with DatabaseCache, 30s with LocMemCache
    return stats_cache.get('key')
```

Global variable (super fast) version:

```
_cache = {}

def stats_service():
    if _cache.get('key') is None:
        _cache['key'] = data
    return _cache['key']
```

Comment: The cache pickles the value, I'm not surprised that it takes such a long time to pickle a 7MB value. Depending on what you're caching and what you're using it for, there might be better ways.

Comment: That explains it indeed, I totally missed that point. I absolutely don't want to pickle it (obviously 7MB RAM is not an issue). I am caching bit masks (binary numpy arrays) that I reuse in every computation. Would you have any suggestion ?

Comment: I found this: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2396/. My only fear with a global dict is that I use multiprocessing in computations using the cached arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet actually works fine: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2396/

As I understood, [the only problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680902/python-django-global-variables) with using global variables for caching is thread safety, and this no-pickle version is thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

One option may be to use [diskcache.DjangoCache](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/api.html#djangocache). [DiskCache](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/) extends the Django cache API to support writing and reading binary streams as-is (avoid pickling). It works particularly well for large values (like those greater than 1MB). DiskCache is an Apache2 licensed disk and [file backed cache library](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/), written in pure-Python, and compatible with Django.

In your case, you could use ndarray [tostring](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tostring.html) and numpy fromstring methods to quickly convert to/from a Python string. Then wrap the string with [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.StringIO) to store/retrieve in the cache. For example:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

value = cache.get('cache-key', read=True)

if value:
    data = numpy.fromstring(value.read())
    value.close()
else:
    data = ... # Generate 7MB array.
    cachge.set('cache-key', io.StringIO(data.tostring()), read=True)
```

DiskCache extends the Django cache API by permitting file-like values which are stored as binary blobs on disk. The [Django cache benchmarks](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/djangocache-benchmarks.html) page has a discussion and comparison of alternative cache backends.

Comment: Thanks, I am definitely going to try this. I'd really like to use fast memory access instead of disk and avoid a conversion, though (

Comment: @muraveill To avoid using files on disk, increase the `large_value_threshold` setting ([API docs](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/diskcache/api.html#diskcache.DEFAULT_SETTINGS)). Cache writes still persist on disk but reads will happen from a synchronized memory-mapped file. In that case, don't wrap the values with `io.StringIO` just pass the raw byte strings. They won't be pickled. You may need to also increase other cache settings to use more memory.