# Django - store globally some values

Tags: django

I would like to store globally number of sites in my database. In my index view I have something like this:

```
sites_inactive = Site.objects.filter(is_active=False)
sites_all = Site.objects.all()
context['sites_inactive'] = sites_inactive.count()
context['sites_all'] = sites_all.count()
```

I would like to have an access to these variables in my every view. Now I must repeat my code in every view. Is it possible to store these values and simply put it in my base.html file? I mean:

```
Number of sites: {{ sites_all }}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680902/python-django-global-variables

Answer (score 3):

If you use [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) to send context to your templates, then you can  [write your own context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) that adds those variables to the context, and add that to the 'processors' part of your `TEMPLATES` setting, then the variables will be available in every template.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it's a bad idea to litter your code with globals. You should create a context processor as RemcoGerlich has already suggested, however instead of fetching values from the global, you should rely on a cache

```
def my_context_processor(request):

    obj = cache.get('site_stats')
    if not obj:

        sites_inactive = Site.objects.filter(is_active=False)
        sites_all = Site.objects.all()
        obj = {'sites_inactive':  sites_inactive.count(),
               'sites_all']: sites_all.count()}
        cache.set('site_stats',obj)

     return obj
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this, is to use a custom `ContextMixin` and use that in every view. The custom `ContextMixin` should extend the `get_context_data` function.

```
class SiteMixin(ContextMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SiteMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Edit context
        return context

class MyView(SiteMixin, View):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it that way.

processor.py

```
def my_context_processor(request):

    return {'sites_all': Site.objects.all().count,
            'sites_inactive':     Site.objects.filter(is_active=False).count()}
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR, ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'mainapp.processor.my_context_processor',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now I have access to sites_all and sites_inactive everywhere in my app. Is it ok?

Answer (score -1):

Django session is what you are looking for. You can store global data in session and access it in every view by using `request.session.get('num_of_sites')`. Check out this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/) for more information.

If you want to display it in every template better idea is to write context processor for that.

Comment: Yes. Session are unique per user. Better approach for this situation is to write custom context processor.