# Global variable in django changing on its own

Tags: python, django

My code is as below:

```
f=0

def load(request):

    global f
    if f == 0:
        login
        f=f+1
    else:
        some commands
```

the function load is called several times.so every time the function is called value of 'f' will be set to zero?

Comment: no it will remain to the previous value...

Comment: yes it should remain to previous value but its changing sometime

Comment: Is this a django view function? Then yes, it will reset after some time

Comment: a view can live in different threads so global variables in django views will not behave as expected.

Comment: It can also be that OP uses the built-in server that reload on code change and so resets f to 0. Django has much better way to handle access and redirect anonymous users to login, if that's the goal.

Comment: yes @dentemm this is a view function..i din get your second answer..can you tell in detail?

Comment: @zinc I do not have the technical details myself, but I have run into the same problem for one of my Django websites. Afterwards, I found out that views are generally not thread-safe, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680902/python-django-global-variables) for more information