# Why is my global dictionary value is changed in different views in Django?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

In my Django app I have a **global dictionary** that stores some instances of a Class. Valu of this dictionary is being changed by one of my Django views. Then I use that global dictionary inside my other views. The problem is, **in production**, when I access this global dictionary in other views, value of it is changed (global dictionary changes to its initial value).

I deployed Django app on Ubuntu server using Gunicorn and Nginx.

Here is the scenario:

```
my_global_dict = {} # This is the global dictionary with initial value of empty dict

def view1(request):
    my_global_dict["key0"] = myClass() # Adding my class instance to the global dict
    ...

def view2(request):
    print(my_global_dict) # Prints: {}. The global dict is empty in this view and others
    ...
```

**I emphasize that there is no problem in the process in the development environment. Also it works with Apache and IIS with ease. The problem I'm facing is after deploying on Gunicorn and Nginx.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably have multiple instances of Django running on your production setup, but only a single one in testing…?

Comment: Global variables are only global within the same Python process. They can't be shared between processes. Use Django's caching framework (with a backend other than local memory) to have real global objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Django Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680902/python-django-global-variables)

Comment: Yep. Gunicorn uses multiple worker processes where the workers run independently. Changes made to a global variable in one worker won't be reflected in another. Maybe consider storing the variable in the session where different values maps to different classes

Comment: what is your configure gunicorn. over 1 worker?

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I get _cannot pickle '_io.BufferedWriter' object_ error when storing class instance

Comment: @TanThien No it's 3.

Comment: @helena, oh because you use 3 worker, It 'll have 3 instance django running in one pod. when 1 request come, worker master 'll proccess it into 1 of 3 worker (each worker has a different global dictionary). So you see different view. You can set to 1 worker and check again my opinion

Comment: @TanThien, yes it's working now. But now there will be problem in processing concurrent requests right?

Comment: @helena  maybe. The server  will not work performce with request need more cpu, if your server has many resource. You can fix the issue with many worker by use cache to store the dictionary

Comment: @helena If you can't serialize your data then yes, you are in trouble. This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why do you want to store a `BufferedWriter` globally?

Answer (score -1):

By the information in comment, Your issues come from your configure gunicorn with more than 1 worker. Now, you set 3 worker, Your pod will have 3 django running (as worker) in 1 server. when 1 request come, worker master 'll proccess it into 1 of 3 worker (each worker has a different global dictionary). So you see different view.

To avoid the issue. You don't use global variable. You can use cache to store variable. All worker will get same value in cache.A good choice is memcached https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/

Comment: [Local-memory caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) is per process so it won't solve their issue, each worker will have separate cache if you do that.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks. I checked again. Should use `Memcached` with one server. If many servers (such as deploy on k8s), use a server cache as Redis

Comment: Unfortunately, I get cannot pickle '_io.BufferedWriter' object error when storing my class instance in cache.

Comment: @helena can you provide the code that break error and the way that you set cache to store class